# How do I let contributors edit their posts after being approved once?

Tags: users, user-roles, permissions

As above

Background info
Main problem: users pay to post an ad on the website
Solution: they sign up as contributors and I publish their posts once the payment is received, after that they can make any edit to their posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a capability in WordPress called "edit_published_posts". Contributors do not have this capability by default (refer to the [Roles and Capabilities Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#edit_published_posts) to see the out-of-box role configurations).

You can add this capability to the contributor role with code like this:

```
// get the "contributor" role object
$obj_existing_role = get_role( 'contributor' );

// add the "organize_gallery" capability
$obj_existing_role->add_cap( 'edit_published_posts' );
```

This code should only need to be run once--perhaps on activation of a plugin.

If you're not comfortable with code, you can use the [Role Scoper plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) (or something like it) to add this capability to the contributor role.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'm writing my question/clarification here. Where should I put this code? Thanks. :)

Comment: @Drewdavid It's probably best in a plugin file, in a function hooked with register_activation_hook(). If that makes no sense to you, do this: put it in your theme's functions.php file. Then load the site *once* in your browser (to execute the code). Then remove the code from your functions file, and you're done. The code only needs to be run once.